# how to view table data in tcpdf

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, tcpdf

i'm a new one for codeigniter and tcpdf. now i want to show my database table row in pdf. i don`t know how to do that. any one can help me please where i should insert the code and how to write the code.

this is the code for pdf generator

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Createpdf extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("Pdf");
    }

    public function create_pdf() {

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);    

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('lakmini');
    $pdf->SetTitle('RCJ CONSTRUCTIONS');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');   

    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
    $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128)); 

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED); 

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);    

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM); 

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);  

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }   

    // ---------------------------------------------------------    

    // set default font subsetting mode
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);   

    // Set font
    // dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
    // print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
    // helvetica or times to reduce file size.
    $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);   

    // Add a page
    // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
    $pdf->AddPage(); 

    // set text shadow effect
    $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));    

    // Set some content to print
    $html = <<<EOD
    <h1> this is my first pdf </h1>
EOD;
  // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);   

    // ---------------------------------------------------------    

    // Close and output PDF document
    // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
    $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');    

    //============================================================+
    // END OF FILE
    //============================================================+
    }
}
```

this is my db table

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `staff` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `designation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contact_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_experience` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `qualifications` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `nic` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `created` date NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `designation_id` (`designation_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have a code of MPDF library first you have to download codeigniter MPDF library link (http://mpdf1.com/repos/MPDF60.zip) with latest version then extract zip file and paste MPDF library on application/libraries path the use below code --

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>controllerName/PDFFile(method name)">Generate PDF</a>
```

PDFFile Method is --

```
public function PDFFile()
  {
        $data['results'] = $this->common_model->federationPDF_file();
        // it will fetch data from database

          $html = $this->load->view('Print_pdf',$data,true); // here we will pass view file name that contain table data

          $this->load->library('MPDF/mpdf');
          $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8','A4', '12', '', 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9); 
          $mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
          $mpdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
          $mpdf->SetTitle(SITE_NAME);
          $mpdf->SetAuthor(SITE_NAME);
          $mpdf->SetCreator(SITE_NAME);
          $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);

          $search = array("<div class=\"row-fluid\">", "<div class=\"span6\">");
          $replace = array("<div style='width: 100%;'>", "<div style='width: 100%; float: left;'>");
          $html = str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
          $name = "PDF File"; // file name
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
          $mpdf->Output($name, 'D'); 
          exit;
     }
```

My View File Print_pdf --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PDF File</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
</div>
 <h2 align="center">Table Data</h2>
  <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td><b>S.No.</b></td>
        <td><b>First Name </b></td>
        <td><b>Last Name </b></td>
        <td><b>Mobile</b></td>
        <td><b>Address</b></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> 
    <?php $count = 1;
    foreach($results as $s)
        { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['fname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['lname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['mobile']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['address']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php $count++; } ?>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks @saurav i'ii try to do that. but i have no idea where to insert <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>controllerName/PDFFile(method name)">Generate PDF</a>